# Android - Vertical and Horizontal WeightSum

Tags: android, layout

I want to put 4 images on the screen dividing in quadrants and put some text on top of each picture.

**I'm know how to use weightsum in either horizontal or vertical, NOT BOTH.**

[WeightSum](https://i.gyazo.com/7da3f36002aeeb96e06108c7c8789b48.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ProductsFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/img_tube_bending"
    android:src="@drawable/fully_electric"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/img_section_bending_rolls"
    android:src="@drawable/section_bending_rolls"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using LinearLayout, it's much easier to accomplish what you want using a GridLayout. Here's a simple example on how to place 4 images in a quadrants manner:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".GridXMLActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Sun3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Sun3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Sun3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Sun3"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works but when I insert my image it's so big that it goes off the screen. any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
WeightSum work with ParentLayout like..
<LinearLayout
height="match_parent"
width="match_parent"
orientation="vertical">
//if orientation is Landescape weight of child will work horizontally like
<ImageView`enter code here`
width="match_parent"
height="0dp"
layout_weight=".25"  //this layout will tahe 25% of the parent layout in height
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code doesnt work. it just displays all the images vertically and none horizontally

Comment: for Horizontal  <LinearLayout
height="match_parent"
width="match_parent"
orientation="horizontal">
//if orientation is Landescape weight of child will work horizontally like
<ImageView`enter code here`
height="match_parent"
width="0dp"
layout_weight=".25"  //this layout will tahe 25% of the parent layout in height
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

I created a xml layout similar to what you expect. With `TextView` over every `ImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Text 1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Text 2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Text 3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Text 4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```